# Common value configuration in Spring XML

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I have several Spring beans in which one of the property value for all of them are same `String` value. Is there a way where I can define this `String` in XML at one place and refer it in all beans at property value settings?

```
<bean id="somebean" class="test.SomeBean">
   <property name="property1" ref="someValue"></property>
   <property name="commonProperty" value="commonValue"></property>
```

```
<bean id="nextBean" class="test.NextBean">
   <property name="property2" ref="someValue"></property>
   <property name="commonProperty" value="commonValue"></property>
```

How to set `commonValue` in a seperate place and refer it in both places?

Answer (score 6):

Try like this.

```
<bean id="commonConfig" abstract="true">
    <property name="commonField" value="CommonValue"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="class1" class="com.dataclass.Class1" parent="commonConfig">
    <property name="field1" value="value1"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="class2" class="com.dataclass.Class2" parent="commonConfig">
    <property name="field2" value="value2"></property>
</bean>
```

Class1 & Class2 having one common field name "commonField", parent attribute is use for this common purpose only.

In Spring this is called bean definition inheritance(this is not java class inheritance, above example Class1 & n Class not inheriting in their respective java file.)

For more detail, look at Spring doc's [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch03s07.html).

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried it before, but this should work

```
<bean id="commonProp" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg name="original" value="yourString"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then, in every bean you need to reference it:

```
<bean id="somebean" class="test.SomeBean">
   <property name="property1" ref="someValue"></property>
   <property name="commonProperty" ref="commonProp"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: `value` is char[], you need to use `original`

Answer (score 1):

You can define your string properties in some "init_constants.properties" file. Then you should load properties file in spring xml:

```
<bean id="properties"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:mail.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:init_constants.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And after that you can inject this properties using xml:

```
<bean id="somebean" class="test.SomeBean">
   <property name="property1" ref="{$prop1}"></property>
   <property name="commonProperty" value="commonValue"></property>
</bean>
```

or in code using @Value annotation:

```
@Value(value="${prop1}")
private String property1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well If commonValue is string then you can put it in properties file and read it using `@Value annotation`.

Comment: yeah, i know this but i dont want to use a property file.. i'm looking for a way to do it in xml itself... this is just to modify the string in one place if any changes occurs, else i need to modify in all the beans...